# How to customize select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, html-select

I want to set background-colors in my select_tag in Rails application

My current haml code

```
= select_tag :color_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@colors, "id", "name")
```

generated

```
<label for="car_color_id">Choose color!</label>
    <select id="color_id" name="color_id">
      <option value="1">White</option>
      <option value="2">Red</option>
      <option value="3">Green</option>
   </select>
```

I want to set

```
<label for="car_color_id">Choose color!</label>
    <select id="color_id" name="color_id">
      <option value="1"><span style="background-color: #ffffff;">White</span></option>
      <option value="2"><span style="background-color: #ff0000;">Red</span></option>
      <option value="3"><span style="background-color: #00ff00;">Green</span></option>
   </select>
```

Hex tags in my database

Comment: Doing that using CSS may probably be easier

Comment: it appears styling option works only in firefox. please check this http://jsfiddle.net/fHyAd/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use this one to generate the output as you suggested:

```
= select_tag :color_id, options_from_collection_for_select('<span style="background-color: {#@colors};">{#@colors}</span>', "id", "name")
```

OR

```
= select_tag :color_id, options_from_collection_for_select('<span style="background-color: '+@colors+';">'+@colors+'</span>', "id", "name")
```